# Are these two distinct definitions of purely atomic measure spaces equivalent?

Tags: measure-theory

In measure theory, there are two distinct definitions of purely atomic measure spaces.

1.Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a measure space, a set $E$ is called an atom for $P$ if it satisfies the following conditions: (1) $P(E)>0$, and (2) for any $F\in \mathcal{F}$, either $P(E\cap F)$ or $P(E-F)$ equals $0$. If each measurable set with positive measure contains an atom, then $P$ is considered purely atomic or simply atomic (see Johnson, Roy A. “Atomic and Nonatomic Measures,” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 25, no. 3 (1970): 650–55).

2.A measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is called purely atomic if, for any $E\in \mathcal{F}$ with $P(E)>0$, there exists a countable and disjoint collection of atoms $E_{k}\subset E$, such that $P(E)=P(\cup E_{k})$.

Are these two definitions equivalent? If so, how can this be proven?